# How can over-expanded flow go out of nozzle when it has less pressure than ambient pressure?

Tags: jet-engine, fluid-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, rocket, flow

We know that over expansion in flow means that nozzle exit pressure of flow is lower than ambient pressure at specific altitude. It gets narrower while exiting nozzle causing loss in efficiency.

My question is;

How can over-expanded flow with less pressure than ambient pressure go out of nozzle and go into ambient pressure which has more pressure than it?

It sounds weird to me because in this case, flow go towards high pressure zone from low.
We might say flow gained kinetic energy as well as momentum before in combustion chamber, but for it to move towards nozzle and turbine, it must still have more pressure than ambient pressure, so that it can move.

I am confused to be honest.
Can you help?

Comment: As soon as the flow reaches the ambient pressure it detaches from the nozzle and it just continues "straight on" without following the nozzle contour anymore. But let's wait for an answer from some expert here.

Comment: Good reading [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine_nozzle).

Comment: @sophit, actually the wikipedia page says it only actually detaches when overexpanded by about 40% (until then it will just slow back down a bit to match the ambient pressure).